# in a grails 3 app, what is spinner and do I need application.js?

Tags: grails, bootstrap-4, grails-3.0, grails3, grails-3.3

grails 3 comes with bootstrap 3. I want to create my own main.gsp layout based on grails 4, i.e. replace the default main.gsp with something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <asset:link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-ico" />
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="DAM"/></title>
    <g:layoutHead/>
</head>
<body>
<g:layoutBody/>
<div class="footer" role="contentinfo"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

At the bottom of the default main.gsp is this:

```
<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;">
    <g:message code="spinner.alt" default="Loading&hellip;"/>
</div>

<asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
```

The question is, should I include these?  In all my years using grails, I have never seen a spinner appear in the UI, so am not sure if this actually works?

I am guessing I don't want application.js?

Also not sure what this is for, as it has no content:

```
<div class="footer" role="contentinfo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The question is, should I include these?

Only if you ever want to display the spinner.  The default `main.css` defines a style for the spinner:

```
.spinner {
    background: url(../images/spinner.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat transparent;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Adjust that however you find appropriate.

The default sitemesh layout contains a `div` with that style and has the `display` set to `none` so it won't be displayed.

```
<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;">
    <g:message code="spinner.alt" default="Loading&hellip;"/>
</div>
```

A typical use of this is if you have some Javascript which does an action such that you want to display the spinner while that action is happening, that Javascript can set that `display` attribute and that will cause the spinner to be displayed until something sets that attribute back to `none`.

> In all my years using grails, I have never seen a spinner appear in
>   the UI, so am not sure if this actually works?

It does unless you have made some changes that might interfere with that.

> I am guessing I don't want application.js?

It is hard to say if you want that or not.  It really depends on what your app is doing.  The default `application.js` for a 3.3.9 app pulls in several other `.js` files...

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js.
//
// Any JavaScript file within this directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// You're free to add application-wide JavaScript to this file, but it's generally better
// to create separate JavaScript files as needed.
//
//= require jquery-3.3.1.min
//= require bootstrap
//= require popper.min
//= require_self
```

If you don't want those pulled in then you may not want `application.js`.  Of course you can edit `application.js` to include whatever it is that you do want to pull in.

> Also not sure what this is for, as it has no content:
>
> ```
> <div class="footer" role="contentinfo"></div>
> ```

That element is there as a placeholder for you to render common footer elements.